# StreamTokenizer.nextToken skipping too many tokens?

Tags: java, stream, token, tokenize

I have the following code which should go through each token, and when the specified characters appear in sequence it means that a comment has begun or ended.

I created the last if statement to execute some code if the position is not between the comments.

```
int commentFound = -1;
                int commentEnded = -1;
                do {
                    int token = st.nextToken();
                    switch (token) {
                        case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF:
                            System.out.println("End of File encountered.");
                            eof = true;

                        default:
                            if ((token == '<')) {
                                System.out.println(st.sval);
                                if (st.nextToken() == '!') {
                                    System.out.println(st.sval);
                                    if (st.nextToken() == '-') {
                                        if (st.nextToken() == '-') {
                                            if (st.nextToken() == '-') {
                                                System.out.println("Comment Found on line number: " + st.lineno());
                                                commentFound = st.lineno();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } 
                            else if ((token == '-')) {
                                if (st.nextToken() == '-') {
                                    if (st.nextToken() == '-') {
                                        if (st.nextToken() == '>') {
                                            System.out.println("Comment Ended on: " + st.lineno());
                                            commentEnded = st.lineno();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if ((commentFound != -1) && !((st.lineno() > commentFound) && (st.lineno() < commentEnded))) {
```

The comment opening tag is always being found, however the closing tag is not always found. After some debugging I think I figured out that the 'nextToken' is skipping too many tokens. Is this possible ? and if so, could there be any way to fix this problem ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

. It looks like you have a bug in end token detection. You need to provide source text. 
Your code currently not recognizes end like this `cccc--->` as it returns cccc--- as whole word token.

Comment: No the end token detection is correct, that's how the comments end in my files

Comment: You should provide full code of the method and tokens that you are trying to match, its hard to guess what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: All I want is to be able to recognize that the comment is starting and ending, I do not know if I have reasoned it correctly

Comment: That was the error yes, do you suggest any other way of tackling this problem please?

Comment: If you are just looking for comments how about reading each line of the file and then using String.indexOf() or String.matches() to look for start/end comment string.